# Enabling plugins (shovel and stream) while defining my rabbitmq docker container for testcontainers

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, testcontainers

Does anybody know how can I define a rabbitmq container object with the specified docker image and also enabling the shovel and stream plugins?

I need to use this against my integration tests in order to test out the functionalities.

My code for now is the following:

```
@Container
protected RabbitMQContainer container = new RabbitMQContainer(DockerImageName.parse("rabbitmq").withTag("3-management"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [RabbitMQContainer.withPluginsEnabled](https://javadoc.io/static/org.testcontainers/rabbitmq/1.15.3/org/testcontainers/containers/RabbitMQContainer.html#withPluginsEnabled-java.lang.String...-)?

```java
@Container
protected RabbitMQContainer container = new RabbitMQContainer(DockerImageName.parse("rabbitmq").withTag("3-management"))
   .withPluginsEnabled("rabbitmq_shovel", "rabbitmq_stream");
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that part with withPluginsEnabled. Thanks, works fine.